# Column is Timestamp, but after to_records it is BigInt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe.  It contains 306 columns, about 40% are datetime columns.  I convert all of the datetime columns using pd.to_datetime.

`ta[TotalTimeCols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

After this, in the dataframe they appear as:

```
2020-07-02 07:58:00
2020-07-06 19:40:00.000001
2020-07-10 13:15:00.000001
2020-07-13 19:18:00
```

When I check the dtype, it says timestamp.

```
opendt = ta.at[0,'Open_Date']
print(type(opendt))
```

I convert the DF to a list using:`listta = ta.to_records(index=False).tolist()`
The dates shows as BigInt:`1593676680000000000` and it is an int dtype.
My end goal is to insert this dataframe into a SQL table with a tuple and executemany.  This also means the data types need to line up.

What do I need to do to fix the timestamps properly, so the output is of the timestamp format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`?

I have tried adding "unit = 's'" to the to_datetime, but it had no affect.

I also tried doing pd.to_datetime for individual column, but no affect: `ta['Open_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ta['Open_Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` (along with adding unit = 's' to this line of code).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

We can convert `opendt` column to `numpy array, record array or a list` directly.

**Input**

```
d = """opendt
2020-07-02 07:58:00
2020-07-06 19:40:00.000001
2020-07-10 13:15:00.000001
2020-07-13 19:18:00
"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df.opendt = pd.to_datetime(df.opendt)
df
```

**Input DF**

```
    opendt
0   2020-07-02 07:58:00.000000
1   2020-07-06 19:40:00.000001
2   2020-07-10 13:15:00.000001
3   2020-07-13 19:18:00.000000
```

**There are few options:**

**1. Convert to numpy array then convert to a list**

```
list(df.opendt.values)
```

**Output**

```
[numpy.datetime64('2020-07-02T07:58:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-07-06T19:40:00.000001000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-07-10T13:15:00.000001000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-07-13T19:18:00.000000000')]
```

**2. Convert to record array then convert to a list (which you are doing)**

```
list(df.to_records(index=False))
```

**Output**

```
[('2020-07-02T07:58:00.000000000',),
 ('2020-07-06T19:40:00.000001000',),
 ('2020-07-10T13:15:00.000001000',),
 ('2020-07-13T19:18:00.000000000',)]
```

**3. Convert directly to list**

```
df.opendt.tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[Timestamp('2020-07-02 07:58:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-06 19:40:00.000001'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-10 13:15:00.000001'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-13 19:18:00')]
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions.  One thing I am having troublle with, the suggestions work on 1 column.  I have 306, which 40% being datetime columns.  I need this info to be in a tuple to insert into SQL table.  

On option 2, if I do ```listta = list(ta.to_records(index=False))```, it gives me error.  In the variable explorer, it shows "[record,record,record....].  If I try to open it, it says "The error message was: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer".

Option 3, does provide a list of timestamps.  Option 1, provides a list of numpy datatime 64 objects.

Comment: I thought I just needed to convert the datetime columns in a different way.  But I guess the problem is with to_records in this case.  So I don't know how to transpose this suggestion across the 306 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the date col, just convert that column only straight to list.  You can convert to string format if you like.  The .to_records command is changing the data type.  See this toy example:

```
ta = pd.DataFrame({'Open_Date': ['2016-03-01 23:51:27.822', '2016-03-02 22:22:33.285', '2020-05-20 03:52:12.739']})

ta['Open_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ta['Open_Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

ta['Open_Date_as_string'] = ta['Open_Date'].astype(str)

listta = ta.to_records(index=False).tolist()

list2 = ta['Open_Date'].tolist()
list3 = ta['Open_Date_as_string'].tolist()
```

to get this for listta and list2 and list3:

```
[(1456876287822000000, '2016-03-01 23:51:27.822'), (1456957353285000000, '2016-03-02 22:22:33.285'), (1589946732739000000, '2020-05-20 03:52:12.739')]

[Timestamp('2016-03-01 23:51:27.822000'), Timestamp('2016-03-02 22:22:33.285000'), Timestamp('2020-05-20 03:52:12.739000')]

['2016-03-01 23:51:27.822', '2016-03-02 22:22:33.285', '2020-05-20 03:52:12.739']
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions of tolist().  You did show me that it does change the dtype appropriately.  What I am not fully understanding is how I translate this method across 306 columns to result in a tuple I can then insert into a SQL table.  Any guidance on that?

Answer (score 0):

The answers by our two esteemed collegues changed how to think about this problem.  As a result, I found a way that works vs. to_records:

`listad =  list(map(tuple, array.reshape((489, 306))))`

It provides a list of tuples that are all in the correct format.

Thanks everyone!